# After upgrading to 13.04 clicking on trash gives "Malformed URL trash://"

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, trash

After upgrading to 13.04 when I click on the trash can icon in the launcher to view files in the trash gives the following error "Malformed URL trash://".

I checked and the "~/.local/share/Trash/" folder is present.  I searched and the only hit I can find is about kbuntu issues.  I am not running Kbuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: I noticed something that may be significant.  I do not like the Nautilus file manager.  Instead I use Dolphin.  I have not changed anything to do so. I just open dolphin instead of Nautilus.  Typically this means that file dialogs still open in a Nautilus window.  However I noticed that my trash is opening in a Dolphin window instead.  Other file dialogs are still opening in a Nautilus window.  Could this be causing the "Malformed URL trash://" error?  Any ideas how to clear this up?

Answer (score 1):

Dolphin has a problem with handling paths pointing to 'Trash'.
When launching the Trash by clicking on the trash can, the dolphin windows is launched with URL: `trash://` which is not what it is expecting. Instead, according to dolphin, it is expecting the correct path to be `trash:/`
You may have (unintentionally) made dolphin the default file manager for opening windows.
Undo that by following the steps below:

1. Install exo-utils

   ```
   sudo apt-get install exo-utils
   ```
2. Run it

   ```
   exo-preferred-applications
   ```
3. In the Utilities tab, under File Manager, select `Nautilus` back and select close.

After that, try to open trash again, **it will open correctly in Nautilus, not in dolphin.**

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager