# Change trash icon command in Unity

Tags: unity, nautilus, trash, dolphin

I have recently replaced my default file manger from Nautilus to Dolphin, so I would like when I click on the trash icon (in left narrow panel), Dolphin opens trash folder not Nautilus. For this I've set Dolphin as the default file manger.

Now, when I click on the trash icon, Dolphin opens and shows a message saying

```
Malformed URL trash://
```

Apparently clicking on the trash icon causes a command to run. But in Dolphin URL `trash:/` works fine.

How can I change the command that runs when user clicks on the trash icon? I should replace `trash://` to `trash:/` there.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/313822/295286

Comment: possible duplicate of [After upgrading to 13.04 clicking on trash gives "Malformed URL trash://"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/294380/after-upgrading-to-13-04-clicking-on-trash-gives-malformed-url-trash)

Comment: The links given in the comments just say "Don't use Dolphin, use Nautilus", which is not really a solution. Are you opening the trash from a Desktop icon or from within Dolphin itself?

Comment: Also, what DE are you using? I presume Ubuntu since you mention Unity.

Comment: @crimsonspectre From Unity launcher. I am also using Ubuntu/Unity.

Comment: Does opening the trash from within Dolphin work?

Comment: @crimsonspectre Yes.

Comment: At least that is a workaround for now. I'll investigate more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug related to Dolphin with a fix on the way.  https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353181